# Parallel Resonance for Wireless Power Transfer

Tags: analog, wireless, resonance

I have two 50 uH coils. I'm using a 68 nF capacitor for each the primary and secondary coils. This puts the resonance frequency to about 86.313 KHz. The primary coil is in series with the 68 nF capacitor and the secondary coil is in parallel with the 68 nF capacitor. There is no load on the secondary side.

The issue is I noticed that the closer the coils to each other, the lower the voltage measured on the secondary. The further the coils apart, the higher the voltage measured on the secondary side.

I did notice that if the coils are directly on top of each other, and I lower the frequency to around 65 KHz, the voltage on the secondary is at its highest, but the voltage quickly disappear when the coils are a little bit apart.

I tried to put the secondary coil in series with the capacitor which seems to have solved the problem, but the efficiency is really bad even when the coils are directly on top of each other.

I watched a lot of videos on wireless power transfer and it seems this issue was never brought up.

I'm I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to _edit your question_ with some more detail.  Namely, in one place you say the secondary is unloaded, but in another you mention efficiency.  If the secondary is unloaded then by definition the power transfer is zero and, hence, the power transfer efficiency is zero.  When you mention efficiency, you say "is really bad" -- can you put that into engineering units?  I.e., what's your percentage of power transferred?  Please also include a sketch with dimensions showing coil diameter, and the separation **in engineering units**.

Comment: This should explain why you get detuning effects: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/398038/wireless-power-transfer-inductive-vs-resonant-mode/398104#398104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-tuned resonators tend to give double-peak response when over-coupled. A LTspice simulation where coupling between coils is varied (simulating moving one coil closer/further):
[image: circuit double-tuned coupled coils LTspice]
[image: frequency response]